# Why can't I send ETH? (Mist 0.7.2 OSX Yosemite)

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, mac-osx, bug

My account has thousands of ETH in it, but MIST says this:
"We can't estimate your gas usage properly, as you need at least 1 ether in your account."

My Mist and geth are all updated to the latest versions.
Also my node always syncs to the latest block when opening Mist, but once Mist is open it stops syncing.

Comment: What os and Mist version are you running? What address are you trying to send to (contract or normal?)

Comment: OSX Yosemite. Mist 0-7-2. Trying to send to Contract

Comment: The same thing is happening to me too.  Yosemite with mist 0.7.2.  Once the wallet ui starts it seems to stop syncing at all.

Comment: Here is another report of the issue happening. Github issue was opened last night: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/558 FWIW, I'm on El Capitan and 0.7.2 and it's working fine. Ugh. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4hsv88/problem_with_sending_from_the_ethereum_wallet/

Comment: Can you guys do console log screenshots and post your node.log (osx: ~/Library/Application Support/Mist/node.log (Open Home folder > Show View Options > Show Library Folder) for this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/558

Comment: I deleted the blockchain and synced overnight with `--fast`.  Was still happening again. Just learned how to send a transaction from the command line instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in 0.7.2 (as well as some previous versions?) that seems to occur when you use the "send everything" function to send to a contract.

If you send everything but 0.1 ETH the transaction should go through.

---

There is a separate syncing bug that seems to be occurring quite frequently with Macs. Some people have had success with the following:

- restarting computer
- installing new version of geth
- deleting chaindata folder and then using geth --fast to resync.
- going back to Mist version 0.6.2.
- Uninstalling all versions Mist and reinstalling (if you have like 0.6.2 and 0.7.2 both on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue yesterday trying to send ethers to [TheDAO](https://daohub.org/).

It's an issue with the IPC connection. See my answer to [Is the Mist Wallet stable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/is-the-mist-wallet-stable/3685#3685) for details on how to diagnose it (Mist console).

To get Mist working so you can send your transactions, start Mist check the Mist console (Developer -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Wallet UI). You will see a "IPC Connection Error" in red. Mist will retry the IPC connection after a few minutes and will usually start working. You will see a gas estimate on your send transaction screen, or if you browse your watched contracts, your READ FROM CONTRACT and WRITE TO CONTRACT fields will be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ethereum Wallet 0.7.3 with geth 1.4.3-rc solved the IPC Issue for me.

For that geth needs to be downloaded from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases since the geth version shipped with Ethereum Wallet 0.7.3 is 1.3.6.

Comment: They don't have it for mac