# How do I keep my Ethereum Wallet synchronised after the initial synchronisation

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have successfully installed and synchronised Ethereum Wallet and it has correctly brought in my test Ether purchase.  How do I resynchronise to ensure more current transactions are recorded on my account?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything but wait. The current sync status is displayed on the top of the wallet window and the chain is continuously synced as when running the wallet you also run a geth node.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same thing on one of my machines. (Running Mist 0.7.3 and Geth 1.4.x or 1.5, on Linux Mint [which is Debian-based and presumably should just work].)

I believe there's actually a bug here. Mist *should* keep itself synchronised, but isn't doing.

Similar behaviour was reported in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-cant-i-send-eth) previous thread. Though the main topic of that thread was not being able to send Ether, the OP reported that Mist wouldn't continue to sync once opened.

**Edit:** See [this](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/616) bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run Geth again, [don't forget to specify `--cache`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4210/42), such as `geth --cache=1024`.  It will help, especially when you have not synced for a while and have many blocks to download.